# java primefaces how to show enum name of int value from database on xhtml

Tags: database, primefaces, enums, int

Here is the situation and I really don't know what to do.
I want to persist months with jpa and enum where months will be persisted as corresponding int values. I read a lot of similar questions and I know opinions on ordinals and strings and @Enumerated, but I want to use this custom int values and I decided to do this:

```
public enum Months {        
    January(1),
    February(2),
    March(3),
    April(4),
    May(5),
    Jun(6),
    July(7),
    August(8),
    September(9),
    October(10),
    November(11),
    December(12);

    private int intValue;

    private Months(int v) {
        this.intValue = v;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    // Mapping month to int
    private static final Map<Integer, Months> mapMonth = new HashMap<Integer, Months>();
    static
    {
        for (Months m : Months.values())
            mapMonth.put(m.intValue, m);
    }

    //Get month from int
    public static Months getMonthName(int v)
    {
        Months m = mapMonth.get(Integer.valueOf(v));
        return m;
    }

}

@Transient
private transient Months month; //actual enum; not stored in db
@Column(name="month")  
private int monthInt; // enum int value gets stored in db
```

So, I actually persist an int attribute intMonth and use enum names like labels like this in my xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="* #{bundle.month}: " />  
                <h:selectOneMenu 
                    value="#{adminMembershipBean.membership.monthInt}"
                    panelStyle="width:150px"  
                    effect="fade" 
                    var="m" 
                    style="width:160px"
                    filter="true" 
                    filterMatchMode="startsWith">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                    <f:selectItems 
                        value="#{adminMembershipBean.months}" 
                        var="months" 
                        itemLabel="#{months}" 
                        itemValue="#{months.intValue}"/> 
                    <p:column>  
                        #{m} 
                    </p:column>  
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

By the way, here is a **BONUS question** please:
why p:selectOneMenu doesn't show enum names? I know this is a problem and one solution is to use h:selectOneMenu, but then I don't have primefaces style combobox.

So, now I got in my database for example 4 and on xhtml April and that's ok.
But, when I want to read that 4 on other xhtml from database, I can't get April, I get empty cell (here is the extract from the p:datatable):

```
<p:column sortBy="#{membership.monthInt}">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.month}" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{membership.month.getMonthName(membership.monthInt)}"/>
</p:column>
```

If I put just

```
membership.monthInt
```

I get 4.
So, **MAIN QUESTION** how to show month name, that is enum name?
Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it works out of the box. I made a quick example with your enum and primefaces.

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MonthEnumBean
{

    private Months month;
    private int monthInt;
    private String monthString;

    public MonthEnumBean()
    {
        monthInt = 12;

    }

    public Months[] getMonths()
    {
        return month.values();
    }

    public Months getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(Months month)
    {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getMonthInt()
    {
        return monthInt;
    }

    public void setMonthInt(int monthInt)
    {
        this.monthInt = monthInt;
    }

    public Months getMonthString()
    {
        return month.getMonthName(monthInt);
    }
}
```

Sample page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="month" var="month" value="#{monthEnumBean.months}">
        <p:column id="modelHeader" exportable="true">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Month Name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{month}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Int " />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{month.intValue}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:panel>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{monthEnumBean.month}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{monthEnumBean.months}" var="month" itemLabel="#{month}" itemValue="#{mont.intValue}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:panel>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="@form" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
    <p:dialog header="Selected Values" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="display">
            <h:outputText value="Name: #{monthEnumBean.month}" />
            <h:outputText value="Intvalue: #{monthEnumBean.month.intValue}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:panel>
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="Number from database: #{monthEnumBean.monthInt }" />                   
            <h:outputText value="String name of number from database: #{monthEnumBean.monthString}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it so far, but there is still one problem with p:selectOneMenu: it doesn't work well with p:column. It shows int values of enum, not names. Here is the code and apologizes for putting it all in one row, I don't know how to write it in comments: `<p:selectOneMenu value="#{monthEnumBean.month}" var="m">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{monthEnumBean.months}" var="month" itemLabel="#{month}" itemValue="#{mont.intValue}" />
<p:column>  
                   #{m} 
               </p:column> 
    </p:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: If i use this code it works as expected i don't see int values in the select one menu. What do you want to achieve with the code above?

Comment: It's ok, it's working with basic selectOneMenu. The thing is that I wanted for fun to use selectOneMenu with filter and then it only showed me int values. Maybe there is a problem with enum and filter use? Maybe I'm wrong? Right now, I don't have time to play with that. Anyhow, you helped me clarify couple of things and thank you very much.